# Selecting values in a table not in a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (simplified version):

```
create table Schedule(
Id int,
ScheduledData datetime,
UserId int)

create table User(
Id int,
Name varchar(50))
```

In the first table I store all scheduled meetings , linking it to an user.

What I want to is retrieve all the free times an user has. It doesn't have to be very detailed.

For example, if a user doesn't have a meeting scheduled for 07/02/2014 morning (earlier than 12:59:59), display a row with the user's name and date. The same if he has a free afternoon.

What I've tried so far and didn't work is to create a temporary table and fill it with all the days of the month and all the users in my DB. That worked well using a CTE:

```
create table #Temp(
StartData datetime,
EndDate datetim,
UserId int)
```

Then, I did this to display the rows:

```
select U.Name, X.ScheduledDate
from #Temp T
left outer join 
(select S.UserId
from Schedules S
where ScheduledData between @X and @Y) X on T.UserId = S.UserId
left outer join User U on T.UserId = U.Id
where S.ScheduledDate between T.StartDate and T.EndDate
```

It didn't work well and I can't make sense of it. I've struggling with this all day and this is the best I've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could use a little more specification:

- What does a row in 'Schedule' mean?  The 'ScheduledData' column is just one instant in time; is this the start time of the meeting?  How long is the meeting?
- What does it mean to display "all of a user's free times?"  Time is a continuous (well, sort of) quantity.  How should the result be represented?

The spirit of your example seems to be, given a block of time, return a true/false value on whether a meeting occurs in that time.  Let's say you have a table called 'Users' containing each user's ID.  How about creating a table 'time_segments' with three columns 'id', 'start_time' and 'end_time'; you could define any time segment you want for example your 'morning' block, and then fetch the free times with something like:

```
select UserId,all_slots.id
from
( select
    TimeSegments.id, UserId
  from
    TimeSegments
    cross join Users ) all_slots
left outer join
( select
    TimeSegments.id, UserId
  from
    Schedule
    cross join TimeSegments
  where
    Schedule.datetime between TimeSegments.start_time and TimeSegments.end_time
) booked using(id, UserId)
where
  booked.UserID is null
```